# wx.GridBagSizer + wx.StaticBoxSizer: How to automate span calculation

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have the following following window generated by using a function called **CreateStaticBoxSizer** however StaticBox3 contains empty spaces at the end of it which I dont want it to.

I would like it to contain no empty space. I noticed that if I put the span for StaticBox3 to be 7 it gives the result which I want but would like to automate the process of generating a span as opposed to hard-coding it:

[image: BoxSizer containing space]

The code uses a span based on the number of items it creates, so if it creates 8 items within the boxSizer, it uses a span of 8.

I can't understand why this is wrong can someone please clarify? What should the span be corresponding to?

Also as StaticBox::4 is intruding on the row of StaticBox::1 why doesn't it expand like StaticBox::3 does?

The code to generate this is as follows:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.inspection
class MyRegion(wx.Frame):
    I = 0
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="My Region")
        gridSizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(4), pos=(0,0), span=(4,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(4), pos=(4,0), span=(4,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(4), pos=(0,1), span=(4,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(8), pos=(0,2), span=(8,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(6), pos=(0,3), span=(6,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(gridSizer)

    def CreateStaticBoxSizer(self, x=4):
        box = wx.StaticBox(parent=self, label="StaticBox::" + str(MyRegion.I))
        MyRegion.I += 1
        sz = wx.StaticBoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL, box=box)
        for i in range(x):
            sz.Add(wx.StaticText(parent=sz.GetStaticBox(),
                                 label="This window is a child of the staticbox"))
        return sz


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyRegion(None)
    frame.Show()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sizer #3 has a row span of 8, so it has the same height of as the sum of the sizers #0 and #1, and this is what results in the gap as the two sizers have 2 labels which take more vertical space than one.

There are probably ways to make it work `wxGridBagSizer` but IMO this sizer should (almost) never be used anyhow. For any kind of normal layout you should use `wxFlexGridSizer` and `wxBoxSizer` instead.

Comment: The number of elements though are equal.  sizers #0 + sizers#1 = sizers #3 why is there a gap? Is it not considering the elements?

Comment: This is exactly why there is a problem: the height of #3 is too big for its contents because it's equal to #0+#1 instead of what it really needs.

Comment: :) Thanks I now understand the remark about the gridsizer. I cant use it easily since the elements inside it do not really give its size.